# uninstalling addin removes the "Excel" entry in the registry

Tags: setup-project, setup-deployment

I have VSTO addin and on uninstall, in registry HKLM->Wow6432->Software->Microsoft->office->excel->addin, both excel and addin is removed from the registry. Because of this the other addins also get destroyed. "MyAddin" is my custom addin.

Registry entries are mentioned below. The properties of everything is "DeleteAtUninstall" is set to false and transitive to true and MyAddin properties are is set to "DeleteAtUninstall" to true. But even then, the "Excel" entry only is removed.[image: Registry entry for addin].

Comment: Why is transitive true? I'm almost certain you don't need that, and it will lead to unpredictable results depending on the property you have associated with the entries.

Comment: @PhilDW-even i tried setting it to false and that dint work